Standard error of mean from in varying sample size for batch simulations
I have three batches of simulations and I calculate a specific property from these (not important for the question). I want to calculate combined SEM for these three batches
Batch | #samples | average | standard deviation | standard error
B1 | n1 | x1 | sd1 | se1
B2 | n2 | x2 | sd2 | se2
B3 | n3 | x3 | sd3 | se3
My approach is as follows
$SE =\sqrt{\frac {(n1-1)*se1^2 + (n2-1)*se2^2 + (n3-1)*se3^2} {(n1+n2+n3-3)} } $
Is this correct approach? Also, I need some paper/book reference for citation. Any help would be really helpful!
